# Confusion related to precision and recall

Tags: precision-recall

I was reading this [paper](http://www.ee.ucr.edu/~amitrc/cvpr2013_context.pdf). However, I have this confusion about the results reported by them. They have given the results in terms of precision and recall. However, their results show that the precision and recall value is greater than 1. I am a bit confused why it is so?

Any insights.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are most probably multiplying it by 100 to obtain percentages, this is often done with respect to metrics like AUC and accuracy as well as precision/recall to emphasize that one is talking about fractions of the full dataset. I suppose it's just a matter of taste.